# Custom error handling in httpd.conf

Tags: apache

Tried implementing custom error handling in httpd.conf file. Able to 
implement it only if I hard code the error message as follows:
 *ErrorDocument 502 "BAD ERROR MESSAGE!!"*
Unable to implement if I use local redirect to custom error page- error.html as below.
 *ErrorDocument 502 /error.html*
Didnot work either with the given sample error pages 
*ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var*

Below is the part of httpd.conf file used

```
#Alias /error/ "<path>/www/error/"
Alias /error/include/ "<path>/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "<path>/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Require all granted
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

#    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var
#    ErrorDocument 404 /error/error.html
#    ErrorDocument 502 "BAD ERROR MESSAGE!!"
#    ErrorDocument 502 /error.html
     ErrorDocument 403 "FORBIDDEN MESSAGE!!"

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Tried testing by having error.html in /www/error/ and also in the document root which /www/html, but did not work.

Please suggest if the location of error.html is wrong or is there anything else to be added in http.conf.

Thanks in advance,
Swathi

Comment: A URL with a trailing slash is in reference to the document root. So if your document root is `/www/html`, then with `ErrorDocument xyz /error/error.html` your error document would need to be located at `/www/html/error/error.html`

Comment: Hi CBroe,  thanks a lot for a quick reply. As suggested I tried having error.html in /www/html/error/error.html. Restarted Apache and tried hitting the page again. Could not get my custom error page. Do I need to change anything in httpd.conf file?

Comment: It worked out when we placed the custom error page in other location under /error dor.

Comment: Note - On the amazon linux the installation comes with a welcome.conf file which defaults 403 to the test page.